# Find Unused mdf and ldf file locations

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We can find mdf and ldf file locations either by using sp_helpdb or using the below command.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.master_files
```

But how can we find ldf and mdf files which are not being used at present i.e Let say you restored one database with new mdf and ldf files and not deleted old mdf and ldf files .

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straight forward easy way.  You can manually do this by searching the server or there is a more complex way spelled out here:

[Finding un-used data files](http://voluntarydba.com/post/2012/08/21/Finding-unattached-database-files-using-xp_cmdshell.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mister Positive.

Comment: I have voted it as useful. Please guide me how to accept the answer.

Comment: You should see an option to accept as the answer.  Click the checkmark under this post, on the left

Comment: Positive, I am trying to find three14 instance but its not returning any results.

Comment: its not returning any results for unused mdf and ldf files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below way:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#AllMDFfiles', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN   DROP TABLE #AllMDFfiles END
CREATE TABLE #AllMDFfiles (mdfFileName VARCHAR(max))

-- Will return all the .mdf and .ldf in C:\ drive, you can change it in ... /d C:\ && dir /b....
INSERT INTO #AllMDFfiles EXEC xp_cmdshell 'cmd /c "cd /d C:\ && dir /b /s | sort | findstr /c:".mdf" /c:".ldf""'

--Will return the mdfs and ldf paths which are not in sys.master_files
select mdfFileName from #AllMDFfiles
Where mdfFileName IS NOT NULL

EXCEPT

SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

Comment: Hi p2k thanks for your answer.unfortunately its taking long time to run and its not returning the expected results too.

Comment: it is expected to take time, depending upon size of drives you have. Can you please let me know what missed from the expected?

Comment: I dont want mssqlsystemresource.mdf ,ldf,model,msdb etc

Comment: Just to add, you can filter it from the #AllMDFfiles table like `Where mdfFileName not like '%mssqlsystemresource.mdf%' OR mdfFileName not like '%model%'...`

Comment: Like this would be difficult and also time consuming hence I will build the  powershell script to perform this activity on 3000 servers at a time.If for 1 server its taking more than 3 mins means howlong do I need to spend time.